# DataTables in bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the default bootstrap datatables for pagination and data display. I want change the records per page dynamically. Right now, they are hard-coded in the select box

```
<div id="example_length" class="dataTables_length">
    <label>
        <select size="1" name="example_length" aria-controls="example">
            <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
            <option value="100">100</option>
        </select>
         records per page
    </label>
</div>
```

Please help me, I have tried to put input button in that place but it is not working.